# Should I inform a business partner who has blocked me about my decision to no longer perform my responsibilities?

Tags: conflict, partnership

**QUESTION:** *My business partner has blocked me from contacting him personally and no longer contributes to our business. Is it necessary to inform him that I no longer will be performing my responsibilities as outlined in our agreement?*

My co-founder 'Bob' and I have a Partnership Agreement to run a small online business - a Youtube channel along with a few social media accounts. His responsibilities were research and recording audio; mine were research, video production, and running the social media accounts. Our venture has not earned any money. Bob also was my long distance relationship boyfriend.

Bob's contribution since the beginning of the venture has been up-and-down. There were a few weeks in which he would record as per the schedule we agreed upon, and then stop after a minor setback (ie. our videos did not receive views/comments). I would ask him from time to time to return to schedule, but he asked me to stop doing so. He did, however, buy a ~$30 microphone to record, of his own volition. He never stated that he no longer wanted to be business partners. I take responsibility for being too lax in negotiating.

On the other hand, I kept to the video production schedule, and I have updated (and continue to update) the social media accounts everyday.

A few months ago Bob and I broke up amicably, but did not discuss what to do with the business. I continued updating the social media accounts during that time. After about a month or so to let the steam cool, I called Bob up to say that I was still interested in running the business and if he was interested in continuing our SOLELY business partnership. He indicated that he was interested in recording again.

The next day I found out that Bob had blocked my personal lines of contact to him.

I have not tried contacting him since then, but I have continued to update the social media accounts. I am no longer interested in doing so, and would like to know if it would be necessary to inform Bob, who is still in a Partnership Agreement with me, that I will no longer be performing my responsibilities as outlined in the agreement. He has not blocked the business's e-mail or social media accounts.

**EDIT:** OP here. To clarify further, as this looks to be a point of confusion, Bob has not performed his responsibilities to the business since several weeks before we broke up. All in all, thank you everyone for your responses and advice.

Comment: It may come under Voluntary Withdrawal, which would lead to the dissolution of the partnership and an equal split up of its (non-existent) assets. However, Bob has not been performing his responsibilities for longer than I. EDIT: To clarify, we each would keep what we have invested/done (so Bob would keep his microphone, etc.).

Comment: Can you please edit the post and make the question obvious? I can only see a story...

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere surely the other party "Bob" should be doing the notification as it is him who has cut lines of communication...

Comment: I personally think him blocking all lines of communication when you said you wanted to continue was his was of saying "I'm not doing my responsibilities"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The business has no assets and no employees. The question does not say if the partnership agreement has any penalties you are worried about running afoul of.

From a legal requirements standpoint, given the lack of stuff to wind down, as long as your Partnership Agreement has no penalties you want to avoid, I see no requirement for notification.

From an interpersonal standpoint, Bob's actions suggest he lacks the drive to keep going with the business but is not comfortable saying that out loud. Given the poor verbal communication history, letting your actions speak for themselves (like he has done) will be the most effective course. (Again, no notification required.)

Answer (score 1):

> would like to know if it would be necessary to inform Bob

Wait to see if he continues to do his. If not, it means hes broke any **potential** partnership agreement terms. Take evidence of this and you do the same. This way you both no longer have to perform your responsibilities and if he does try to take action and say x and y. It means you can show proof that he hasn't been doing them either (just to make sure).

You also stated in the comments that it may come under Voluntary withdrawal which means you equally split non-existent assets so it shouldn't be a problem anyway but take proof just in case, this way you don't have to chase him through every avenue to contact him.

> The next day I found out that Bob had blocked my personal lines of contact to him.

This was likely his way of actually saying "I no longer want to perform these responsibilities". Clearly incapable or unwilling to actually say this when you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are doing the right things so far.

You should take reasonable steps to confirm with him what his plans are. You should also give him a reasonable deadline to get back to you. (A couple of weeks).

If you want to close things off, you should communicate that you are willing to pay for the remaining business assets, which from what I can gather is the value of a used $30 microphone.

Also, you should immediately record all your actions regarding the business and including all attempts to communicate with him.

I would not involve a lawyer. It's honestly not worth the time or the effort, but while things are fresh in your mind, just get it all on paper.

If he does get back to you and you wish to continue, you need to make sure you form a new agreement about how and when the business will dissolve.